# Are de facto Schengen countries exempt from the Covid-19 US travel ban?

Tags: united-states, immigration, covid-19, schengen-area

President Trump's [presidential proclamation](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspension-entry-immigrants-nonimmigrants-certain-additional-persons-pose-risk-transmitting-2019-novel-coronavirus/) specifically defines the countries affected by the ban as the 26 signatories to the Schengen Treaty:

> For purposes of this proclamation, the Schengen Area comprises 26
>   European states: Austria, Belgium, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia,
>   Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Italy, Latvia,
>   Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway,
>   Poland, Portugal, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, and Switzerland.

However, four European states also maintain open or semi-open borders with the Schengen area, namely Andorra, Monaco, San Marino, & Vatican City. Clearly travellers from these countries will also be subject to the separate ban on people that have visited Schengen countries in the last 14 days, but considering the (semi)open borders, there should be no way to definitively prove this status one way or the other.

Are these countries exempt from the ban? Is this an oversight by the Trump administration, or do methods exist to identify travellers from these countries who have recently returned from the Schengen area proper?

Comment: The bigger potential loophole would seem to me to be the non-Schengen EU countries: Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland, and Romania. I'm not sure there's an actual record kept for their residents' entry and exit from the Schengen zone. Although there are no direct flights from the Eastern EU countries to the US, as far as I know, they could fly to the US via Heathrow.

Comment: @Fizz there is no Schengen-wide system for recording entries or exits.  One is being developed, but it will not record data of EU citizens or others who benefit from EU freedom of movement.  I've definitely seen planes from the eastern EU at JFK, though they were from Schengen members.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that none of these countries have their own international airports, and all but Monaco are landlocked, it's effectively impossible for nationals of those microstates to reach the US without visiting a Schengen country.

Presumably, someone from Monaco who travels by boat to the UK and flies from there could get away with entry or any nationals who are currently outside the Schengen area, but I imagine the final decision will come down to an ICE official who will compare the passport to a list of affected countries.

Comment: That would be CBP, not ICE